# Find the line tangent to $9x^2+16y^2=52$ that is parallel to $9x-8y=5$ using the first order Taylor Series

Tags: solution-verification, partial-derivative

> Find the line tangent to $9x^2+16y^2=52$ that is parallel to $9x-8y=5$

By setting $z(x,y) =0$, I used the tangent plane formula or first order TS
$$
h(x,y)=z(a,b)+z_x(a,b)(x-a)+z_y(a,b)(y-b)
$$
$$
h(x,y)=9a^2+16b^2-52+18a(x-a)+32b(y-b)
$$
$$
h(x,y)=-9a^2-16b^2-52+18ax+32by
$$
To make the plane parallel to $9x-8y=5$ at $z=0$, I set
$$
a=1/2\\
b=-1/4
$$
to take the form of the parallel line which then gives me a plane
$$
h(x,y)= 9x-8y -55.25
$$
that is not tangent to the $9x^2+16y^2=52$ but parallel to $9x-8y=5$ at $h(x,y)=0$

What have gone wrong with my solution?

Edit:
If I got $a,b$ correct, the graph should look similar to this and I will simply take $h(x,y)=0$ to get the line I need
[image: graph]

Comment: Do you need to use a tangent plane formula? On a simpler cartesian 2D plane level, collect the $x$ in terms of $y$. This is way you can find the derivative of the ellipse function w.r.t $x$ and find the point where the gradient of the ellipse = the tangent gradient of $\frac{8}{9}$

Comment: @Unexpected Confusion unfortunately I need to apply anything related to partial differentiation since the question in asked in the context of multivariable calculus

Comment: ...  There are clearly only two axis of interest here: the $x$ and $y$ coordinates to the curves and lines.  There is no need to make up a third axis just because you are in a multivariable calculus class.  Occum's Principle: don't add unnecessary variables.

Comment: @Graham Kemp you are right, however I am still curious why my solution gives a wrong answer. I think that it will help my intuitions greatly if I am able to correctly relate the problem to that method. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using the tangent plane formula. That is, as the name implies, used for finding tangent *planes* (so, a 2-dimensional object in 3-dimensional space). What you're looking for is a tangent line which is much different, so when you define your function $z(x,y)$, it actually doesn't at all mean what you want it to and does not define an ellipse. Here's roughly what it looks like:

[image: curved 3D surface]

(https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xyrgbanmmi)

You really just want to represent the two halves of the ellipse in two separate equations and solve it using single variable calculus. $9x^2+16y^2=52$ can be rewritten as $y^2=\frac{-9x^2+52}{16}$ which is $y=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-9x^2+52}}{4}$.

Now, if you write those two parts out separately, you can get the derivative and just find points where the slope of the tangent is equal to your given line and find the equation. You should be getting two tangent lines, since the tangent line at any point on an ellipse has the same slope as the tangent line to the point directly opposite it.

There's probably a more elegant way to represent this and solve for a derivative / obtain the points, but in any case, you *definitely* should not be using a formula designed for three dimensions. $z(x,y)$ is supposed to be a function that takes the $x$- and $y$-coordinate and return the $z$-coordinate at that point, not a relation that determines if a point in 2D is on a figure or not.

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand why I can't use the tangent plane formula. When I defined $z(x,y)$, it's graph is (at least) correct for what is required at $z=0$. When I took $h(x,y)$, it is suppose to give me a plane that ( intersects $z=0$ ) if the parameters $a$ and $b$ are correct, which is also my problem. When I think of applying 3d techniques to a 2d problem by setting $z=0$ or $h=0$, the graph tells me that it is valid

Comment: @qcpz How would the tangent **plane** formula give you a **line** tangent to $9x^2+16y^2=52$ though?

Comment: I think of using the tangent plane with parameters $a,b$ that intersects the ellipse that $z(x,y)$ forms at $z=0$ and is tangent to it if I draw the intersection between the tangent plane $h(x,y)$ and $z(x,y)$ when I set $z=0$. Graphically, it looks like a plane "tangently" slicing $z = 0$ at the ellipse